# Unable to Deploy Spring Boot Application In Openshift

Tags: java, spring-boot, heroku, openshift

I am following the below steps to run my Spring Boot app: https://github.com/debasen/springboot-demo.git in [Open shift](https://www.openshift.com/):

1. Add Red Hat OpenJDK8 to my project.

[image]
2. Next
[image]
3. Add hit repository
[image]

After doing this. I am getting the following Log at Build:

```
Cloning "https://github.com/debasen/springboot-demo.git " ...
    Commit: c3b500b7c27540de6f1ef90734aca8b1a09d6fb6 (Initial Commit)
    Author: Admin <Admin@DESKTOP-78DNBRA>
    Date:   Sun Mar 18 20:48:29 2018 +0530
Pulling image "registry.access.redhat.com/redhat-openjdk-18/openjdk18-openshift@sha256:afe904fd986c4147d1905813eb1a2f5bc3480ecad5b70b4ccfec384271777429" ...
==================================================================
Starting S2I Java Build .....
S2I source build with plain binaries detected
Copying binaries from /tmp/src to /deployments ...
... done

Pushing image docker-registry.default.svc:5000/boot-test1/spring-demo:latest ...
Push successful
```

And Deployment fails with the following log:

```
Starting the Java application using /opt/run-java/run-java.sh ...
ERROR: Neither $JAVA_MAIN_CLASS nor $JAVA_APP_JAR is set and 0 JARs found in /deployments (1 expected)
exec java -javaagent:/opt/jolokia/jolokia.jar=config=/opt/jolokia/etc/jolokia.properties -Xms256m -Xmx256m -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=20 -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=40 -XX:GCTimeRatio=4 -XX:AdaptiveSizePolicyWeight=90 -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=100m -XX:ParallelGCThreads=1 -Djava.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.parallelism=1 -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError -cp . -jar
Error: -jar requires jar file specification
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)
where options include:
    -d32      use a 32-bit data model if available
    -d64      use a 64-bit data model if available
    -server   to select the "server" VM
                  The default VM is server,
                  because you are running on a server-class machine.


    -cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
    -classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
                  A : separated list of directories, JAR archives,
                  and ZIP archives to search for class files.
    -D<name>=<value>
                  set a system property
    -verbose:[class|gc|jni]
                  enable verbose output
    -version      print product version and exit
    -version:<value>
                  Warning: this feature is deprecated and will be removed
                  in a future release.
                  require the specified version to run
    -showversion  print product version and continue
    -jre-restrict-search | -no-jre-restrict-search
                  Warning: this feature is deprecated and will be removed
                  in a future release.
                  include/exclude user private JREs in the version search
    -? -help      print this help message
    -X            print help on non-standard options
    -ea[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
    -enableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
                  enable assertions with specified granularity
    -da[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
    -disableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
                  disable assertions with specified granularity
    -esa | -enablesystemassertions
                  enable system assertions
    -dsa | -disablesystemassertions
                  disable system assertions
    -agentlib:<libname>[=<options>]
                  load native agent library <libname>, e.g. -agentlib:hprof
                  see also, -agentlib:jdwp=help and -agentlib:hprof=help
    -agentpath:<pathname>[=<options>]
                  load native agent library by full pathname
    -javaagent:<jarpath>[=<options>]
                  load Java programming language agent, see java.lang.instrument
    -splash:<imagepath>
                  show splash screen with specified image
See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index.html  for more details.
```

As no jar is created at the time of build the deployment is failing.
While the project in the sample repository https://github.com/jboss-openshift/openshift-quickstarts works fine.
I tried Heroku to host my app. It works fine in [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/). 
But not working in Openshift. Please tell me what am I missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The build log is not reporting an explicit error, but suggests that nothing was built actually:

```
S2I source build with plain binaries detected
Copying binaries from /tmp/src to /deployments ...
... done
```

As [your repo](https://github.com/debasen/springboot-demo) "hides" the app source in a parent folder, try either specifying the [`contextDir`](https://docs.openshift.org/latest/dev_guide/builds/build_inputs.html#source-code) (that is `/`, by default) to `springboot-demo` for your build, or move the app source to the root of your git repository.

You can edit the build Configuration using the `oc` CLI by `oc edit bc/<build_config_name>` or do the same using the web interface by clicking the *"advanced options"* link when you're providing the git repo URL during deployment of the application from the catalog, or by using *Actions* -> *Edit* menu item when browsing the existing build configuration.

Comment: God can not be everywhere. So he created stackoverflow. You are awesome.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error. However, the solution for me was to make the application produce **Jar** instead of **War**.

I use maven to package the application. So, In pom.xml I changed

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

to

```
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```